# Calling Web API 2 with Get is OK but fails with Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am able to invoke `Web Api 2`, from `static html form` with `get` as below.

Web API:

```
public class WebServiceController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/WebService")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(string FirstName, string Surname)
    { 
        //work
        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

HTML Form:

```
<form action="http://localhost:27020/api/WebService/" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" />
    <input type="text" name="Surname" id="Surname" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When I switch from `get` to `post` request with `method="post"` and `[HttpPost]` I am getting the screenshot below on Chrome:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebAPI can't read each method parameter independently. You'll have to encapsulate them:

```
public class WebServiceController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/WebService")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(MyRequest request)
    { 
        //work
        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}

public class MyRequest
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good practice to change web api route which is

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

to

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

after it you will not require to follow get put and post, you can use full name just like MVC routing. eg. http://yourhost/api/WebService/your_action.